# Powershell Grouping

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file as follows:

[image: CSV that holds Service name and Priority]

It contains a windows service and a priority and I want the priority to control the order n which the services start and stop.

I.e stop all priority 1 before priority 2 and so on until priority 9 which would be the last one. After stopping 1-9 in order I also want it to start in order.

Having trouble going about this. I don't want to have 9 different arrays in which I store the groups because it feels inefficient. Any thoughts or suggestions?

```
$Columns = "ApplicationName", "Priority"
$Applications = @()
$Path = "C:\Users\mwalters\Desktop\app-test.csv"
$CSV = Import-csv -Path $Path | Select $Columns 
$Applications += $CSV | Sort -Property Priority 
$AppsToLoopOver = @()

$i = 0

foreach ($Application in $Applications) {
   $ApplicationFromCSV = $Applications.ApplicationName[$i]
   $AppPriority        = $Applications.Priority[$i]

   $AppsToLoopOver += [PSCustomObject]@{
       Priority=$AppPriority;
       ApplicationName=$ApplicationFromCSV
   }
   $i++
}

$Group1 = @()
$Group2 = @()
$Group3 = @()

foreach ($Priority in $AppsToLoopOver.Priority) {
    if ($Priority -eq 1) {
        $Group1 += $Priority + " Group1"
    } elseif ($Priority -eq 2) {
        $Group2 += $Priority + " Group2"
    } elseif($Priority -eq 3) {
        $Group3 += $Priority + " Group3"
    }
}

$AppsToLoopOver
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just sort by priority, but if you specifically want to operate on them as groups, you could use the `Group-Object` cmdlet such as in the following:

```
$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

$ServiceGroups = Import-CSV "C:\Users\mwalters\Desktop\app-test.csv" | Group-Object Priority | Sort Name
$ServiceGroups | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Verbose "Stopping priority $($_.name) services"
    $_.Group | Select -ExpandProperty ApplicationName | Stop-Service -WhatIf
}
```

Remove `-WhatIf` if you're happy with the outcome.

Comment: Clean! Thanks was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: How would I go about looping through each element in a group? i.e if I want it to go through all of group 1 and concatenate the priority with the application name?

Comment: Would you mind raising this as a new question? It will be easier to answer that way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43944636/powershell-loop-through-groups

Answer (score 2):

For grouping structured data use the [`Group-Object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) cmdlet:

```
Import-Csv $Path |
  Group-Object Priority |
  Sort-Object {[int]$_.Name} |
  ForEach-Object {
    # ... do stuff ...
  }
```

Comment: Still new to powershell and didn't know how to quite continue with your suggestion. Thanks for the help!