# Powershell loop through groups

Tags: powershell

I want to loop through the contents of a set of group individually, i.e group 1 contains:

AppReadiness
MessagingService_e88063
BthHFSrv

And I want to loop through the group and append it's priority so it looks like this:

AppReadiness - 1

and so on.

**Here is my code:**

```
function CallServices{

$VerbosePreference = 'Continue'

$ServiceGroups = Import-CSV "C:\Users\mwalters\Desktop\app-test.csv" | Group-Object Priority | Sort Name
#$ServiceGroups

 $ServiceGroups | ForEach-Object {
    "Stopping priority $($_.name) services.."
    "count groups-"
    $ServiceGroups.Count

    tester $ServiceGroups
   }
  }

function tester{
param(
    $ServiceGroups
)

$Applications = @()

ForEach ($ServiceGroup in $ServiceGroups){

    $ServiceGroup | ForEach-Object {

        $application = $_.Group.ApplicationName
        $Priority = $_.Group.Priority 
        $app = $application +"-"+$Priority
        $Applications += $app
    }
    '- - - - - - - - - - '
    $Applications

    $Applications = @()

   }



#$ServiceGroups
#"count within group-" 
#$ServiceGroups[0].count


}


CallServices
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to handle each group in turn you could do this:

```
$ServiceGroups = Import-CSV "C:\Users\mwalters\Desktop\app-test.csv" | Group-Object Priority | Sort Name

$ServiceGroups | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host "Priority $($_.name) services"

    $_.Group | ForEach-Object {
        "$($_.ApplicationName) - $($_.Priority)"
    }
}
```

Or to just go through all the groups in one go do this, although grouping here then becomes redundant:

```
$ServiceGroups = Import-CSV "C:\Users\mwalters\Desktop\app-test.csv" | Group-Object Priority | Sort Name

$ServiceGroups.Group | ForEach-Object {
    "$($_.ApplicationName) - $($_.Priority)"
}
```

This would deliver the same result as the above:

```
$ServiceGroups = Import-CSV "C:\Users\mwalters\Desktop\app-test.csv" | Sort Priority,Name

$ServiceGroups | ForEach-Object {
    "$($_.ApplicationName) - $($_.Priority)"
}
```

Comment: Why bother saving the variable `$app`? Just send it down the pipe as is.

Comment: Yep true, was just mirroring somewhat how his existing code worked (this answer came due to a comment on a previous question and I hadn't realised he had further changed his code). So yeah, only assigned it to $app in case he wanted to manipulate it further.